# Hodge star and non-orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors, orthonormal, exterior-algebra

I am working with the Hodge star and a non-orthonormal basis, and I can't see where exactly something is going wrong.

Let $V$ be an oriented $n$-dimensional vector space, and let $\Lambda V$ be the exterior algebra, considered as a subspace of the tensor algebra $TV$, where my convention is: $a\wedge b=a\otimes b - b\otimes a$, and similarly for $a_1\wedge \dotsm \wedge a_k$ (using all permutations in $S_k$).

Also let $g$ be a metric on $V$, so that we have a metric on $TV$, and thus on $\Lambda V$. Explicitly:
$$\langle a\otimes b,c\otimes d\rangle :=  \langle a,c \rangle\langle b,d\rangle$$
which makes
$$\langle a\wedge b,c\wedge d\rangle :=  2(\langle a,c \rangle\langle b,d\rangle - \langle a,d \rangle\langle b,c\rangle)$$
This definition of $g$ causes the unfortunate fact that if $(e^i)$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$, then $(e^i\wedge e^j)_{i<j}$ will be orthogonal, but each element will have norm $\sqrt 2$.

The volume element is defined as: if $(e^i)$ is an orthonormal basis, then let $\text{vol}_g = e^1\wedge\dotsm \wedge e^n$.

The Hodge star is defined by the equation
$$a\wedge \star b = \langle a,b\rangle \text{vol}_g$$
and is supposed to be an isometry.

**Problem**

Restrict to $n=4$. I tried computing $\star e^1\wedge e^2$.
We know that it should be some multiple of $e^3\wedge e^4$, say
$$e^1\wedge e^2 = \kappa e^3\wedge e^4$$
So we have
$$\kappa e^1\wedge e^2\wedge e^3\wedge e^4 = e^1\wedge e^2\wedge \star (e^1\wedge e^2) = 
2\text{vol}_ge^1\wedge e^2\wedge e^3\wedge e^4$$
But this causes $\kappa =2$, which would mean the Hodge star is not an isometry!
So something must have gone wrong.

I believe I am taking definitions from multiple incompatible setups, but I don't understand what should change. I suspect it is the relationship of:

1. The choice to induce the metric on $TV$ rather than one directly on $\Lambda V$ which makes $e^i\wedge e^j$ orthonormal.
2. The choice of embedding $\Lambda V \subseteq TV$ as I did.
3. The definition of $\text{vol}_g$ (maybe it is just wrong?)

Please let me know if you can find the error in my understanding/computation.

Comment: Your $2$ in the definition of the inner product of the basic two-forms is wrong. I think trying to start with an inner product on the tensor square is an error.

Comment: So is this just some incompatibility with: 1. the choice of metric on $TV$ above and the (common) choice of embedding $\Lambda V\subset TV$,
and 2. the Hodge star?

Comment: Maybe a better question is: If I choose to use the $TV$ metric, what is natural to change in order to compensate? The (definition of the) volume form? The defining equation for the Hodge star?

Comment: To have the Hodge star identity you want, the wedge products of any $k$ orthonormal basis vectors of $V$ must form an orthonormal basis of $\Lambda^k V$. Arrive there however you wish.